# How to find the database id of a cloud firestore project?

Tags: rest, api, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use the Cloud Firestore REST API, but can't seem to find the project id.

Comment: Projet ID or Database ID?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Firestore's REST API is still in beta; we can't generate our own database ids as of yet.

We have to use the default database id which is currently the following (glaringly literal) string:

**`(default)`**

And yes, you have to include the parentheses.

Comment: Is this still valid?

Comment: works for me: projects/my-google-project-id/databases/(default)

Comment: *b r u h*  -_-

I suppose if it works it works

Comment: I was just looking for documentation on the 'databaseId' parameter, thinking I must have missed something because I couldn't find a databaseId to replace '(default)' with. Apparently there's still just one '(default)' database per firebase project?
I'd love to see this point clarified a bit in the documentation, that it's a placeholder for potential features in the future, or whatever.

Comment: I figured this out by inspecting network traffic on the firebase console while viewing the list of indexed of my firestore database. The index names returned by the indexes endpoint indeed contain  `(default)` as database name.

Comment: ffs this took me hours to figure out...

Comment: Here's the docs where it's mentioned. Man, this is dumb. Give us all the same weirdly formatted default database name, don't put it anywhere in the Firebase / Firestore console and require us to know it for a Cloud Function. https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore